# How to add whole directory to js section in asset bundle yii2

Tags: yii2, minify, assetbundle

How to add whole directory to js section in asset bundle yii2

I think that this will be something like this

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/myModule/*',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

I want this because i don't want each time (when i minify my css or minify my js) write in asset bundle something like this

```
'css/site.min.css',
```

Instead of writing `'module.min.js', 'module2.min.js'` i'd like to write something like regex (to add whole directory) that will gather all files from directory and add them to my asset bundle and my `$js` array will looks like next

```
'js/myModule/*',
```

So how to implement it? Is there anywhere is 'ready from the box' solution?
Please, help. 
I asking this because 'is it normal that i (i use gulp and different minificators etc) write in asset bundle `module.min.css` or `module.min.js`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relyin on [Yii2 docs' assets page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) there is no way to implement this feature out of the box.

But you can override `init()` method of your `AppAsset` class to implement parsing the folder (vie [FileHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles()-detail)) and add it to `$this->js` array dynamically.

The other way to do that (which I personally use), is to parse `assets.json` file, which is used by gulp file, and add every js/css file that is generated by gulp. Here is code sample

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\base\Exception;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset',
        'yii\validators\ValidationAsset'
    ];

    public $packages = [];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $content = @file_get_contents(\Yii::getAlias('@app/assets.json'));
        if (!$content) {
            throw new Exception('Could not read assests from path ' . \Yii::getAlias('@app/assets.json'));
        }
        $assetsData = json_decode($content, true);

        if (!empty($assetsData['scripts'])) {
            foreach ($assetsData['scripts'] as $script) {
                if (in_array($script['name'], $this->packages, true) && $this->loadInAjax($script)) {
                    $this->js[] = 'scripts/' . $script['name'] . '.js';
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($assetsData['styles'])) {
            foreach ($assetsData['styles'] as $style) {
                if (in_array($style['name'], $this->packages, true) && $this->loadInAjax($style)) {
                    $this->css[] = 'styles/' . $style['name'] . '.css';
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using @naffiq s suggestion, I came up with this code:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

abstract class StarAssetBundle extends AssetBundle
{

    private $filePathOptions = [
        'only' => ['*.js'],
        'recursive' => false,
    ];

    public function init()
    {
        $realSourcePath = \Yii::getAlias($this->sourcePath);

        $fileHelper = new FileHelper();

        $jsFiles = $this->js;

        $parsedJsFiles = array();

        foreach($jsFiles as $uri){
            $path = $this->strReturnIfContainsStarAtEnd($uri);
            if($path){
                $dir = $realSourcePath.'/'.$path;
                $arrFiles = $fileHelper->findFiles($dir, $this->filePathOptions);
                foreach ($arrFiles as $file) {
                    $jsFilePath = $path . '/' . basename($file);
                    array_push($parsedJsFiles, $jsFilePath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($parsedJsFiles, $uri);
            }
        }
        $this->js = $parsedJsFiles;

        parent::init();
    }
    private function strReturnIfContainsStarAtEnd($str){
        $strLen = strlen($str);
        $pos = strpos($str, "*", $strLen-1);
        if($pos !== false){
            return substr($str, 0, $strLen-2);
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now I can add all .js files coding only the path and adding * at the end - **'js/myModule/*'**